# Not able to call command from within the script

Tags: linux, shell

i have installed oversip & when i try to execute the command "oversip" from shell,

```
[root@vhost1111 ~]# oversip
NOTICE: <executable> OverSIP 1.3.8 starting...
```

it gets executed.
But when i put that command in a shell script and then run the shell script.
It says command not found.

```
[root@vhost1111 ~]# ./init.sh start
Switch to user oversip
Starting oversip: ./init.sh: line 21: oversip: command not found
```

----Oversip Path----

```
[root@vhost1111 idcuser]# which oversip
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/oversip
```

----$PATH-----

```
[root@vhost1111 idcuser]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/oversip:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-320/bin:
/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin/:/usr/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

Contents of init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PID="--pid /var/run/oversip/oversip.pid -u oversip";
if [ ! -d /var/run/oversip ]; then
mkdir -p /var/run/oversip
fi
if id -u oversip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
echo "Switch to user oversip";
else
adduser -u 106 -g 99 --shell /bin/false -b /var/run oversip
chown oversip /var/run/oversip 
fi

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
case "$1" in
start)
echo -n "Starting oversip: "
oversip $PID
echo
touch /var/lock/subsys/oversip
;;
stop)
echo -n "Shutting down oversip ??: "
killproc oversip
echo
rm -f /var/lock/subsys/oversip
;;
status)
status oversip
;;
condrestart)
if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/oversip ]; then
$0 stop
$0 start 
fi
;;
reload|restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
echo "destroy existing connections during a restart."
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

I added 'type oversip' and also 'which oversip' in the script:  Below is the output for both.

```
./init.sh: line 20: type: oversip: not found
which: no oversip in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
```

Comment: Where is the executable oversip ? (output `which oversip`) It looks like it is in the root `PATH`, but not in the `PATH` of user oversip.

Comment: can you post the contents of init.sh or at least the line that calls oversip. also do this command `which overship` from your shell and tell us the results.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of 'which oversip' and contents of $PATH.

Comment: And about the content of `init.sh`, and the `$PATH` of user `oversip` ? These are the relevant things here.

Comment: @Levans  
I have also added the contents of init.sh just now. Please check.

Comment: Try adding `type oversip; which oversip` immediately before `echo -n "Starting oversip: "` under `start)` in that script. I'm willing to bet it's a simple path issue, and that will confirm it. If so, it might be as simple as specifying the full path to the executable. (You *might* also want to echo $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the latter if the software requires any particular libraries of its own.) You *may* need to promote the script to use /bin/bash rather than /bin/sh for `type` to work, but I think you'll be OK as it is.

Comment: Please check the updated question now.

Answer (score 0):

Your init script tells you

```
which: no oversip in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
```

Your shell tells you

```
# which oversip
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/oversip
```

What directory do you think you need to add to the PATH in the init script?

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm...320/bin"
```

Comment: I added:
`export PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/:$PATH`

to the init script , but it is still not working.

Comment: When i check $PATH from init script it shows PATH contents as given in the updated question. But when i do `which oversip`, why does it show : `no oversip in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)` , 
what is `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` ? ,as it dosent match with my $PATH contents.